# Spring Boot - perform object and image upload in one @POSTMapping operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file-upload, multipart

I am learning Spring Boot, especially loading images.

The following two end points work well -  one for loading image into the server and other for loading an object (in this care a PersonModel object).

```
@PostMapping("/user/testUpload")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel> testObjectUpload(@RequestBody PersonModel persontModel) throws 
    Exception {
        personService.upload(persontModel);
        BaseResposeModel baseResposeModel = new BaseResposeModel();
        baseResposeModel.setMessage(persontModel.getFirstName()+ " Success");
        return new ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel>(baseResposeModel,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@PostMapping("/user/personImageUpload")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel> testUploadImage(@RequestParam("productImage") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{

            personImageService.uploadImage(file);

            BaseResposeModel baseResposeModel = new BaseResposeModel();
            baseResposeModel.setMessage("file uploaded successfully");
            return new ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel>(baseResposeModel,HttpStatus.OK);
             
        
    }
```

Is it posible to combine the two into one `@POSTMapping` operation?  How can we do that?  I would appreciate if someone can show me how to do it.  Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, see this video for more information : [Upload File with spring boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IcVSoCF2fs&list=PLJJMbxdZZVvp1wh7Tis2OoBtN2s1l06pU&index=3)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It can work. Instead of **@RequestBody** for PersonModel variable, use **@RequestPart**

```
public ResponseEntity<BaseResposeModel> testObjectUpload(@RequestPart PersonModel persontModel, @RequestParam("productImage") MultipartFile file) {
...
}
```